# mysql query :parse error IN clause

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I am trying to execute a mysql query in express js application

```
    function(req,res){
           var params = [req.body.category,1]
           db.query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE category IN ? AND status=?",[params],function(error,result){
           console.log(error);
  })
```

Here is the input value of `req.body.category` : ["pen","book"]

**UPDATE**

Based on comments i've changed my query and the input

```
 final query "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE category IN ("+req.body.category+")"
 

input:"'f','test'"
```

However this works fine but query still  vulnerable to sql injection attack so i enclosed it with `db.escape(req.body.category)` but it returns empty result

Comment: Updated with error message